# Angular Select with async in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular2-directives

Try as I might, I can't get an angular select with async working fully.  I can get it *mostly* working - but not everything.

imagine the controller looks like:

```
 $scope.stuff = {};
 $scope.stuff.blah = "SOME_KEY";
 External.list().then( function (data ) {
   $scope.stuff.sourceSystems =data; 
 });
```

then this displays the values nicely

```
 <select ng-model="stuff.blah">
 <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in stuff.sourceSystems | orderBy" value="{{key}}">{{key}}</option>
 </select>
```

but this for some reason has an extra, blank choice at the start:

```
<select ng-model="stuff.blah" ng-options="key for (key, value) in stuff.sourceSystems | orderBy"></select>
```

however - in neither case is my existing value, which I set into SOME_KEY - selected.    in the first case, the first value in the list is selected - in the second case, a blank value is selected.  In both cases - the underlying bound value is SOME_KEY.   HOWEVER - as soon as I actually change the selected value, by dropping it down - the bound value (blah) - correctly changes.

This is in a directive with bindToController set to true.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: that's what I do in my second example - actually - I just found a workaround - if I use ng-options and in the promise handler bind to the full object - ie $scope.stuff.blah = data[ "SOME_KEY"] it's working - but seems a bit of a hack :(

Comment: are you sure the response in `data` doesn't have an empty key? If you can post your response from the list it will be easier for us to help debug this.

Answer (score 1):

$scope.stuff.blah <- has String key

,in ng-repeat , repeated Value is Object (included angular hashkey)

```
try this, and read ng-options

 <select ng-model="stuff.blah" ng-options="system.key as system.key for system in stuff.sourceSystems | orderBy">
 </select>
```

Comment: tried that - but it didn't work - got nothing in the list.  Note - sourceSystems is annoying in that the key doesn't exist anywhere in the data - it's literally a hashtable where the "key" item only exists in the key of the table - not in any of the items in the table